# My 'menu' class does not stick to the top of the screen and height auto does not work when i do padding

Tags: html, css

Okay i know the tittle is bit confusing but here is a description. I have a header tag inside html and a full screen background in css. On top of the screen is menu
which is suposed to stay there (not to stick to the top of the screen while scrolling). Also i never had this problem before when i set height to auto and i set padding for an 'a' element height does not follow the padding of the a element and then there is a gap between background and top of the screen. So in order to fix that i wrote `margin-top: -20px;` but then it looks like this.
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCbaq.png)
And if i remove margin-top it looks like this:
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngQOf.png)

Again i never had this problem before and here is code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Smart Hosting | Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: Roboto;
 }

body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

header {
background: url(./img/server.jpg) 50% 50%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.menu {
background: #1C2F51;
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
 }

.menu ul {
list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
display: inline;
background: #25CFB0;
padding: 30px;
}

 .menu a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `inline` for your li elements. Margins doesn't always do what you expect on inline elements.

```
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px; //to remove the blank space at the top
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #25CFB0;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQgBpV